# Skype crash on start up after update

Tags: 12.04, skype

I recently updated skype from 4.2 to 4.3.
Now skype always crashes immediately after starting without any error message.
I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out I just needed to delete the hidden  `~/.Skype` folder in my home directory.

Deleting the subfolder `~/.Skype/my-skype-username` would also solve the issue.

Comment: did not solve the issue for me...